# Why Code::Blocks include C++ features when I'm coding with C?

Tags: c, gcc, autocomplete, codeblocks

I use Code::Blocks as my IDE. I know that for example `nullptr` and `new` only exist in C++, But when I type `nu..` Code::Blocks's auto_completion can complete the  `nu..` either with `NULL`which exists in C or `nullptr` which exists only in C++. It is strange that when I use `nullptr` in my code it shows me this error:

> first use in function

and it is obvious that compiler doesn't recognize it but it's included `nullptr`
as a code.

I don't know where the problem comes from. From inappropriate setting such as bad compiler configuration or something else?

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Is this really a problem you wish to dedicate time fixing?

Comment: @DeiDei So what is your suggestion ?

Comment: Ignore it. I am not a Code::Blocks user, but it's presumably due to code-completion being the same. That is, since the syntax of C and C++ is similar, they just decided to make it 2-in-1.

Comment: @NothingNothing Can you suggest me a useful IDE ?

Comment: It all depends from the person to person. You should search through the Internet until you find one that suits you. In the end, an IDE is nothing more than a tool. I personally use CLion, but it's a paid IDE.

Comment: @Ceeker Try KDevelop. It is really a great IDE.